# Select entire cell text on single click for cell edit instead of double click in primeng table

Tags: css, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am using a p-table with cells populated with integer data and is editable. Now on single click the input text becomes visible with the cursor at the end of the cell text. The requirement is to select the entire content of the cell text on single click edit itself. Basically single click should behave like the double click. I added 2 events in app.component.html for input:

```
(focus)="focusInFunction($event)"
(dblclick)="eventEmitDoubleClick($event)"
```

But simply calling eventEmitDoubleClick() from focusInFunction() function does not work.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please?

Comment: `(focus)="$event.preventDefault();focusInFunction($event)"` does not work?

Comment: I added  (focus)="$event.preventDefault();focusInFunction($event)" and called this.eventEmitDoubleClick(event) from focusInFunction(event) function. But still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can try something like this:

```js
$('#highlight').on('click', function() {
  var Target = document.getElementById("highlight");
  Target.select();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="hello world" id="highlight">
```

Comment: Yes this worked. Just had to tweak the Target declaration as:                                         
 var Target = document.getElementById("highlight") as HTMLInputElement;